# How to remove selective <script> tag among multiple <script> tags?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have multiple `<script>` tags on a webpage. I want to remove a few  `<script>` tags from among them. How can I do using Nokogiri?

For example, I have five `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file 1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file 2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file A"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file B"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file C"></script>
```

I want to remove only `"script file 2"` and `"script file B"`.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code you need to show us the minimal code that demonstrates the problem. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to figure out the problem for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the corresponding nodes with [`xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#xpath-instance_method) and [remove](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#unlink-instance_method) them :

```
doc.xpath("//script[@src='script file 2' or @src='script file B']").remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS I'd probably use something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file 1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file 2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file A"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file B"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script file C"></script>
EOT

doc.search('script').select { |script| script['src'][/file [2B]$/] }.map(&:remove)
puts doc.to_html

# >> <script type="text/javascript" src="script%20file%201"></script>
# >> 
# >> <script type="text/javascript" src="script%20file%20A"></script>
# >> 
# >> <script type="text/javascript" src="script%20file%20C"></script>
```